# Laptop randomly thinks lid is closed

Tags: 20.04, dell, logout, lid

I have an issue whereby my laptop randomly turns my screen off or logs me out. From /var/log/auth.log it seems that the system thinks the lid is closed:

```
Sep 15 09:36:44 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[648]: Power key pressed.
Sep 15 09:36:46 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[648]: System is rebooting.
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: New seat seat0.
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event3 (Power Button)
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Lid Switch)
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event7 (Intel HID events)
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event8 (Intel HID 5 button array)
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: New session c1 of user gdm.
Sep 15 09:38:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Sep 15 09:38:45 michael-Latitude-7280 polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.33 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Sep 15 09:38:51 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:38:54 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:38:54 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Sep 15 09:38:54 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Sep 15 09:38:54 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user michael by (uid=0)
Sep 15 09:38:54 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: New session 2 of user michael.
Sep 15 09:38:54 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user michael by (uid=0)
Sep 15 09:38:54 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Sep 15 09:38:55 michael-Latitude-7280 gnome-keyring-daemon[1866]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Sep 15 09:38:55 michael-Latitude-7280 gnome-keyring-daemon[1866]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Sep 15 09:38:57 michael-Latitude-7280 polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.82 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Sep 15 09:39:00 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Sep 15 09:39:00 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Session c1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Sep 15 09:39:00 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Removed session c1.
Sep 15 09:39:00 michael-Latitude-7280 polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.33, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Sep 15 09:39:03 michael-Latitude-7280 PackageKit: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
Sep 15 09:39:03 michael-Latitude-7280 PackageKit: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Sep 15 09:39:59 michael-Latitude-7280 pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Sep 15 09:39:59 michael-Latitude-7280 pkexec[3600]: michael: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/michael] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Sep 15 09:40:15 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:40:15 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Suspending...
Sep 15 09:40:16 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:40:17 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:40:20 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): conversation failed
Sep 15 09:40:20 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): auth could not identify password for [michael]
Sep 15 09:40:25 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Sep 15 09:40:27 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:40:29 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:40:29 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Sep 15 09:40:38 michael-Latitude-7280 gnome-keyring-daemon[1866]: couldn't allocate secure memory to keep passwords and or keys from being written to the disk
Sep 15 09:40:38 michael-Latitude-7280 gnome-keyring-daemon[1866]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/11, but it's already registered
Sep 15 09:40:39 michael-Latitude-7280 gnome-keyring-daemon[1866]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/11, but it's already registered
Sep 15 09:41:04 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:41:04 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Suspending...
Sep 15 09:41:06 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:41:06 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): conversation failed
Sep 15 09:41:06 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): auth could not identify password for [michael]
Sep 15 09:41:12 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:41:13 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Sep 15 09:41:15 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:41:17 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:41:17 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Sep 15 09:41:20 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:41:21 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 su: (to nobody) root on none
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 su: (to nobody) root on none
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 su: (to nobody) root on none
Sep 15 09:43:49 michael-Latitude-7280 su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Sep 15 09:44:38 michael-Latitude-7280 su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Sep 15 09:45:51 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:45:51 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Suspending...
Sep 15 09:45:52 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:45:53 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:45:53 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:45:53 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:45:56 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:45:56 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:45:57 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:45:57 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Sep 15 09:46:08 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Sep 15 09:47:21 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:47:21 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Suspending...
Sep 15 09:47:21 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:47:22 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:47:23 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): conversation failed
Sep 15 09:47:23 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): auth could not identify password for [michael]
Sep 15 09:47:33 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Sep 15 09:47:34 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:47:35 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:47:35 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:47:37 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:47:37 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Sep 15 09:47:41 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:47:42 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:48:19 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid closed.
Sep 15 09:48:19 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Suspending...
Sep 15 09:48:19 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Lid opened.
Sep 15 09:48:20 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:48:28 michael-Latitude-7280 systemd-logind[649]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Sep 15 09:48:41 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:48:45 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:48:45 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Sep 15 09:48:49 michael-Latitude-7280 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:48:53 michael-Latitude-7280 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:48:53 michael-Latitude-7280 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=michael rhost=  user=michael
Sep 15 09:48:55 michael-Latitude-7280 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:48:58 michael-Latitude-7280 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 09:48:58 michael-Latitude-7280 sudo:  michael : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit auth.log
Sep 15 09:48:58 michael-Latitude-7280 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 15 10:02:12 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Sep 15 10:02:13 michael-Latitude-7280 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
```

Timeline of events:

-09:36:44 I manually rebooted the system

-09:40:15 First event where laptop screen goes black and/ore logs me out

-09:40-09:45 A series of 'crashes' where I am logged out and the system log seems to think the laptop lid is shut. I did not physically move the lid during this period.

Can anyone spot something from this log that could be causing the issue? Or things I could do to investigate further?

System:

-Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, 5.11.0-34-generic (also happened with kernal at least as early as 5.11.0-27)

-Dell Latitude 7280

Other observations: Happens regardless of whether charging or not. Seems to happen more often while typing, versus using mouse.

Comment: Oh wow, I think that's it! I got a new bracelet about ten days ago that clips together using a magnet. A quick check shows that when wearing the bracelet and moving my hand to a typing position, it turns the screen off. I removed the bracelet - and it seems to have stopped happening. I will monitor for a few hours to be sure this is the issue - but I think you found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closed-lid sensor is a magnetic switch in the palm rest area and a magnet on the top of the screen bezel. Are you wearing some kind of magnet or magnetic element on your wrist? Try to move a small magnet around the palm rest area and see if the issue is fixed. Also, you may want to try a static discharge (power-off, unplug from AC, remove battery, hold power button for 30 seconds, then put the battery in place and plug again into AC and power-on to test if it worked).